# What constitutes "idle" CPU during T2 CPU credit calculation?

Tags: amazon-ec2

The documentation for EC2 T2 "burstable" types say:

> The baseline performance and ability to burst are governed by CPU
>   credits. Each T2 instance continuously receives CPU credits at a set
>   rate, depending on the instance size. **T2 instances accrue CPU credits
>   when they are idle**, and use CPU credits when they are active. A CPU
>   credit provides the performance of a full CPU core for one minute.

What I don't understand is what does *idle* mean? All instances use some CPU > 0%, so is there are CPU usage figure under which the instance is considered to be "idle"?

Surprisingly, given the liberal usage of this term, I cannot find a definition of "idle" anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question, the [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) documentation for [CPU Credits in T2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits) could be more precise here indeed - the introductory blog post [New Low Cost EC2 Instances with Burstable Performance](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/low-cost-burstable-ec2-instances/) provides a better explanation, see the table in the middle:

> The column labeled "Baseline Performance" indicates the percentage of
>   single core performance of the underlying physical CPU allocated to
>   the instance. For example, a t2.small instance has access to 20% of a
>   single core of an Intel Xeon processor running at 2.5 GHz (up to 3.3
>   GHz in Turbo mode). A t2.medium has access to 40% of the performance
>   of a single core, which you (or your operating system, to be a bit
>   more precise) can use on one or both cores as dictated by demand.
>
> The column labeled "CPU Credits / Hour" indicates the rate of CPU
>   Credits that the T2 instance receives each hour. **CPU Credits
>   accumulate when the instance doesn't use its baseline allocation of
>   CPU, and are spent when the instance is active**. Unused CPU Credits are
>   stored for up to 24 hours. *[emphasis mine]*

Comment: Great, so in the case of T2.small, for example, which has a baseline of 20% CPU, when it's under 20% we are earning at a fixed rate, when it's above we are spending at a variable rate as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits

Comment: Exactly - this transparent approach (including appropriate [CloudWatch metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits)) is a rather significant and competitive improvement over the previous throttling model for the respectively infamous `t1.micro` instances.

Comment: @DanGravell, you earn at a variable rate "For example, if a t2.small instance had a CPU utilization of 5% for the hour, it would have used 3 CPU credits (5% of 60 minutes), but it would have earned 12 CPU credits during the hour, so the difference of 9 CPU credits would be added to the CPU credit balance"

Answer (score 2):

"idle" is notoriously hard to define in general for Linux servers. On general level, idle should be any time not spent on user-mode, system-mode, low priority mode, i/o waiting or interrupts -- with the special provision that given the right kind of workload, i/o wait time could be converted to user-mode time (for another process).

However, on the question of idle of AWS t2, this doesn't hold. It didn't hold for t1 either (due to "stolen" time), but even that doesn't explain t2 behavior. I've run into scenarios where idle time (as reported both by Linux top and by AWS CloudWatch) is way above the documented threshold levels, yet the instance is losing CPU credits instead of gaining them. I believe this to be an accounting error on Amazon's side, and until it is fixed, trying too hard to understand how CPU utilization and idle are defined will be a waste of time..

I've posted some illustrative charts on AWS's support forums, where hopefully they will respond. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=568026#568026

Comment: We may be having the same issue with a medium instance for mail processing. Credits accumulated linearly with no usage at all, and now deployed, there's a gradual drop even with maximum utilisation in 5 minute buckets of less than 1%. It may be that the idle threshold is a small fraction of 1%, but that would not make the instances useful. Responses from Amazon to your ticket and others do suggest that the credits calculation is not working as intended though.

Comment: Amazon staff posted an explanation of the system, which appears to be more complex than the documentation leads to think: not only is there a maximum balance of credits for each T2 instance type, but credits earned 24h ago will expire from the balance.

That is, a t2.small will earn 12 credits per hour, maintain a maximum balance of 288 credits, but ALSO any credits it earned 24 hours ago will be subtracted from the balance. This means instances over 24 hours old will lose credits faster than you would expect, and long-term balance will likely be closer to the initial than maximum value.

Comment: @osama thanks for adding that. From the charts I suspect there's even *more* to it, but it's working out for us at the moment which is what matters :) We've increased average load on a medium since Friday and are watching to see what happens now.

Answer (score 0):

This is something like below

If you are using micro instance that runs on max 10% single core throughout. suppose times come when your server is consuming 5% of single core, so it consider remaining 5% of computing power as idle. This 5% keeps on accumulate off-course for 24hrs only. Now if you have this accumulation and mean while your server is starving for computing power than it can borrow from this accumulated computing power. For this computing power they  have used a fancy word called CPU Credits.

I Googled out and found good explanation on some blog http://themindtracks.com/amazon-launches-new-low-cost-ec2-instances-burstable-performance/