# EC2, Tomcat, Amazon Linux and Out of memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat, memory-usage, memory-leak

I use AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run my application on **Tomcat 8.5** with **Java 8** running on 64bit **Amazon Linux**. I use **t3.small** which according to specification has 2vCPI and 2.0 GB of memory.
My configuration looks like this:

[image]

After some time (2 days) my application runs out of memory. System logs show:

```
[ 4627.110117] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name

[ 4627.204880] [ 8096]     0  8096   191163    10071     105       4        0             0 aws

[ 4627.209125] [ 8466]    91  8466  1132802   432642     998       8        0             0 java

[ 4627.217630] [ 8540]    48  8540   328251      999      98       4        0             0 httpd

[ 4627.221861] [ 8541]    48  8541   328285     1158      98       4        0             0 httpd

[ 4627.226172] [ 8542]    48  8542   328280     1265      98       4        0             0 httpd

[ 4627.234663] [ 8655]     0  8655   134228     5330      81       3        0             0 cfn-hup

[ 4627.273722] [ 8738]    48  8738   328280     1297      98       4        0             0 httpd
.......

[ 4627.299082] Out of memory: Kill process 8466 (java) score 865 or sacrifice child
[ 4627.303727] Killed process 8466 (java) total-vm:4531208kB, anon-rss:1730568kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Cloud Watch log shows:
[image]

Does it mean t3.small is not enough to run my server without memory issues or I have memory leak in my java app? Can I fix it somehow by changing configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run an app that needs 1.5GB on a 2GB machine - that's quite a stretch as there won't be much left for the system, disk caches, other processes, etc. I wouldn't expect a great performance even if it didn't crash.

Run it on `t3.medium` and see if it still crashes. If it does you may have a memory leak. If it doesn't it means you app simply needs more RAM than `t3.small` can provide.

If then you still insist on using `t3.small` even if it doesn't provide an adequate memory size you can try adding a swap space (e.g. 2GB) - that will increase the amount of memory the app will be able to allocate but some of will be very slow, because it's on a disk. It may or may not matter, depends on how the app uses the allocated memory.

Also be aware of the *CPU Credits* that T2/T3 instances use - you may experience a slow-down after a period of fast processing. It's described here: **[On clarifying t2 and t3 working conditions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/937443/on-clarifying-t2-and-t3-working-conditions/937461#937461)**

The bottom line is: **use a right-sized instance**. You don't want to run out of memory of CPU power, especially not in production.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Totally agree. Really does sound like a memory leak. Use a bigger instance, if it happens after a longer time check your code. You can have Java do a heap dump to examine what objects are on the heap, if you do that on your local machine after it's been running a while the memory leak may become obvious.